# SQL: Have two two columns of old and new SKUS. Need to pull into a single column with new skus if any

Tags: sql, case

I have two columns with data from Table1 that have the SKU number and New SKU Number. My goal is to query this data as a single column as shown in the 'Desired' Table

```
+-------+--------+    +---------+
| SKU   | NEW_SKU|    | Desired |
+-------+--------+    |---------+
| null  | 1      |    | 1       |
| null  | 1      |    | 1       |
|  2    | null   |    | 2       |
|  2    | 3      |    | 3       |
|  2    | 5      |    | 5       |
+-------+--------+    +---------+
```

Currently I have:

```
SELECT 

SKU
CASE WHEN (SKU IS NOT NULL AND NEW_SKU IS NOT NULL) THEN new_sku
WHEN (SKU IS NULL AND NEW_SKU IS NOT NULL) THEN new_sku
ELSE SKU END AS Product_number

FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` here:

```sql
SELECT SKU, NEW_SKU, COALESCE(NEW_SKU, SKU) AS Product_number
FROM Table1;
```

The `COALESCE` function, as used above, would use the `NEW_SKU` value if it be non `NULL`, otherwise would fall back to using the `SKU` value.

Comment: At first I tried

 `SELECT SKU, NEW_SKU, COALESCE(SKU,NEW_SKU) AS Product_number
FROM Table1;`

Double checked and it didn't work. Then I realized the order in COALESCE is important!

SO FOLKS OUT THERE LOOKING TO DO THE SAME PLEASE Look at Tim B's solution.